# HTML 5 Skew code

Tags: javascript, html

I need to simulate the effect of skewing an image, like Photoshop, using Javascript. Do you guys know how to do that in Javascript?

What kind of geometry calculation is applied to the `<canvas>` context? **I can't use CSS for this**, because it has to be modified dynamically.

[image]

Comment: This can be done with CSS3 alone.

Comment: this cannot be done with CSS because it has to be modified on the fly by javascript. I said that on the question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/playcanvas.asp?filename=playcanvas_transformb&preval=1,0,0,1,0,0

Answer (score 2):

CSS `transform: skew();` will do this for you with no Javascript.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/MtWBy/

#### Output

[image: kitties]

#### CSS

```css
#original {
    margin: 55px 10px 0 10px;
}

#vertical {
    margin: 30px 20px 0 0;
    transform:             skew( 0, -30deg );
        -ms-transform:     skew( 0, -30deg );
        -moz-transform:    skew( 0, -30deg );
        -o-transform:      skew( 0, -30deg );
        -webkit-transform: skew( 0, -30deg );
}

#horizontal {
    margin: 55px 0 0 0;
    transform:             skew( -30deg, 0 );
        -ms-transform:     skew( -30deg, 0 );
        -moz-transform:    skew( -30deg, 0 );
        -o-transform:      skew( -30deg, 0 );
        -webkit-transform: skew( -30deg, 0 );
}

.image {
    background-image: url( 'http://placekitten.com/100' );  
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px; 
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;  
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<div id="original" class="image"></div>
<div id="vertical" class="image"></div>
<div id="horizontal" class="image"></div>
```

Comment: this cannot be done with CSS because it has to be modified on the fly by javascript. I said that on the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @RubberDuck You can still use `.skew()`, you can just set classes in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with CSS3 alone:

```
img {
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
}
```

**[Live Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/3124509)**

Note, I only used webkit, but it's the same for all other modern browsers.

Comment: this cannot be done with CSS because it has to be modified on the fly by javascript. I said that on the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @RubberDuck: You did not say that in the question, and I think it can still be done using JavaScript and CSS3.